# SweetAlert no funciona en el panel de adminstración de django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, sweetalert

He importado tanto `JQuery` como `Bootstrap` en el panel de administración (no estoy seguro de si `SweetAlert` depende de estos, pero los he añadido de todas formas) del siguiente modo (dudo que el problema sea la llamada del `sweetAlert` por que he hecho copia/pega de la documentación oficial)

```
class Media:
    css = {
            "": ("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" ),
            "": ("sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.css"),
            "": ("css/admin.css",)
    }
    js = (
            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js",
            "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.min.js",
            "js/stretchy.js",
            "js/admin-incidencias.js",
     )
```

Pero continua sin funcionar, esto es lo que aparece en el panel de administración al lanzar el `sweetAlert`.

[image: Error SweetAlert]

Mi idea es utiliazarlo para hacer una petición `AJAX` para subir archivos y que el usuario reciba un "feedback" de que el fichero se está subiendo (los ficheros pesarán bastante). Desconozco si ya existe algún plugin que resuelva mejor mi necesidad.

ACTUALIZACIÓN:
No es problema de los ficheros importados.
Por si siriviera de ayuda os muestro la parte de `JQuery` donde invoco el `sweetAlert`. No tiene nada fuera de lo corriente.

```
$('[value=Grabar]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal("Has pulsado el boton de guardar");
 });
```

La idea es llamar ahí dentro a la función `AJAX`que elimine el fichero, pero por el momento ni tan solo funciona el `sweetAlert` de confirmación.

Comment: Dinos algo más, que error te da o algo. ¿La consola no dice nada?

Comment: No salta ningún error, simplemente me aparece la ventana modal ahí al final de la página. Ni siquiera la consola del navegador muestra ningún error, es decir, encuentra los recursos y todo por lo que no es problema de importar los ficheros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, en contra de lo que yo pensaba era problema al importar los ficheros css y js. Así es como tiene que estar:

```
    class Media:
    css = {
        "all":("css/admin.css",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css",)
    }
    js = (
        "js/stretchy.js",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.min.js",
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js",
        "js/admin-incidencias.js",
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega las siguientes lineas por CDN

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert-dev.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js

Este es un ejemplo que utilize con Php y Ajax, espero te sirva:

```
function objetoAjax(){
            var xmlhttp=false;
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {

            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (E) {
                xmlhttp = false;
            }
        }
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
              xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            return xmlhttp;
        }

        function eliminar_semestres(idsemestre){
          divsemestres = document.getElementById('divsemestres');
            swal({
          title: "Esta Seguro",
          text: "Su Dato, no podra ser recuperado",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
          confirmButtonText: "Eliminar",
          cancelButtonText: "No, Cancelar!",
          closeOnConfirm: true,
          closeOnCancel: true
        },
        function(isConfirm){
          if (isConfirm) {
                ajax=objetoAjax();
                ajax.open("GET", "../phpcrud/eliminar_semestres.php?idsemestre="+idsemestre);
                ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (ajax.readyState==4)
                    {
                    divsemestres.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
                    }
                }
                ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                ajax.send(null)
          }
            else{}
        });
        }
```

[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: He cambiado los archivos por las urls que me has pasado y continua sin funcionar, no es problema de los archivos que yo tenía descargados en local. Gracias de todos modos.